# Better Algorithm for finding smallest Antiprime for a given integer

Tags: java, algorithm, hashset

I found this question on HackerRank, where we were supposed to find the smallest AntiPrime number (a positive integer is antiprime if and only if it has more divisors than any other positive integer smaller than itself).

So, if user inputs 5 , then the smallest antiprime number would be 6, as 6 has more divisors than any number b/w 1 to 5.

My approach :- Store the number of divisors for each number 1 to n in a hashset and then from n+1 check the integer that has more divisors than the one in the HashSet.

```
public static int send(int n)
    {
        HashSet hs = new HashSet() ;
        for(int i=1 ; i<=n ; i++)
        {
            hs.add(div(i)) ;
        }    
        for(int i= n+1 ; ; i++)
        {
            if(Collections.max(hs).compareTo(div(i)) < 0 )
            {
                return i ;
            }    
        }    
    }    
    public static int div(int n)
    {
        int ctr = 0 ;
        for(int i=1 ; i<=n ; i++)
        {
            if(n % i == 0)
                ctr++ ;
        }    
        return ctr ;
    }
```

The logic works perfectly, but in all the testcases it returned timeout, since the complexity as I see it is O(n^2) .

So, please suggest me a better algorithm, that can do well in relatively lesser time.

Comment: For the people downvoting the question, please mention the reason. I find this rude.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow...

Comment: your loop in div should only go up to teh sqrt of n.

Comment: you should store the max of your Hash set before the second loop in send, to avoid looking up the same value many times...

Comment: Because n*2 has the same factors as n with an extra factor of 2 as well as n you know your number with the most factors less than x will be greater than floor(x/2) so your first loop in send should start at int(n/2)+1 because integers concatenate towards zero.

Comment: from 1 to n, you dont need to store the number of divisors for all number. just keep the max number of divisors and keep updating it.

Comment: @RenukaDeshmukh That actually requires the same number of comparisons as calling max once at the end on all the stored values, you save a little memory but it won't have much effect on run-time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Set<>` data-structure, then you can store everytime the number of divisors hits a peak (Antiprime numbers). You can then call something like `ceiling()` to get the next largest one from the number, so for `5` it would return `6` in `O(logn)` time. Also, for the output, use a `StringBuilder` and build the result and then output it. For me it didn't work at first with `System.out.println()`, but do `StringBuilder` and then `append()` the result. At the end, do `.toString()` on the `StringBuilder`. For reference I came 8th overall (out of 2000+) in the contest so it worked for me then and got perfect.

Answer (score 1):

I incorporated the modifications mentioned in the comments here:

```
public static int send(int n)
    {
        HashSet hs = new HashSet() ;
        for(int i=int(n/2)+1 ; i<=n ; i++)
        {
            hs.add(div(i)) ;
        }
        int markToBeat = Collections.max(hs);
        for(int i=n+1 ; ; i++)
        {
            if(div(i) > markToBeat )
            {
                return i ;
            }
        }    
    }    
    public static int div(int n)
    {
        int ctr = 0 ;
        for(int i=1 ; i<=sqrt(n) ; i++)
        {
            if(n % i == 0)
                ctr++ ;
        }    
        return ctr ;
    }
```